# Uploaded CSV data not being sent to the database after making changes on the webpage

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I have a MVC web application where users can upload a CSV file, view its contents on a webpage, make changes to the data, and then import the updated data into a database. I have implemented the functionality, but I'm facing an issue where the original CSV data is being sent to the database instead of the updated data.

I have a controller action method named `Upload` in my `ImportController.cs`
file that handles the file upload and data import process. After reading the uploaded file and storing its contents in the `model.FileContent` variable, I display the data on the webpage using an editable table. Users can modify the table cells and then click the "Import" button to save the changes to the database.

However, when I inspect the `updatedTableData` array in the JavaScript code, it contains the updated values as expected. But when I check the database, it still contains the original data from the uploaded file.

Here is the relevant code from my project:

##### Upload.cshtml

```
@model ImportModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Import Page";
}

<center>
    <h1>Import Data</h1>
</center>

<form asp-controller="Import" asp-action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="my-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fileInput">Select File:</label>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="file" class="form-control-file" accept=".csv, application/vnd.ms-excel" required>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.FileName))
{
    <h4>Uploaded File: <span id="fileName">@Model.FileName</span></h4>
}

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.FileContent))
{
    <h4>File Contents:</h4>
    <div id="fileContents" class="table-responsive">
        <table id="editableTable" class="table table-bordered">
            @foreach (var row in Model.FileContent.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                <tr>
                    @foreach (var cell in row.Split(","))
                    {
                        <td contenteditable="true">@cell</td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <button id="importBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Import</button>
    <button id="clearBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary">Home</a>
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        var importBtn = document.getElementById('importBtn');
        var clearBtn = document.getElementById('clearBtn');
        var fileNameElement = document.getElementById('fileName');
        var editableTable = document.getElementById('editableTable');

        fileInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            if (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    document.getElementById('fileContents').innerHTML = e.target.result;
                    importBtn.disabled = false;
                    clearBtn.disabled = false;
                    fileNameElement.textContent = file.name;
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            } else {
                fileNameElement.textContent = '';
                document.getElementById('fileContents').innerHTML = '';
                importBtn.disabled = true;
                clearBtn.disabled = true;
            }
        });

        clearBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            fileInput.value = '';
            fileNameElement.textContent = '';
            document.getElementById('fileContents').innerHTML = '';
            importBtn.disabled = true;
            clearBtn.disabled = true;
        });

        editableTable.addEventListener('input', function () {
            importBtn.disabled = false;
        });

        importBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            var updatedTableData = [];
            var rows = editableTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
                var rowData = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                    rowData.push(cells[j].innerText);
                    cells[j].setAttribute('data-original-value', cells[j].innerText);
                }
                updatedTableData.push(rowData);
            }
            // Send updatedTableData to the server for database import
            console.log('Updated table data:', updatedTableData);
        });
    </script>
}
```

##### ImportController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ImportController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ImportController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(ImportModel model)
    {
        if (model.File != null && model.File.Length > 0)
        {
            model.FileName = Path.GetFileName(model.File.FileName);

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await model.File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                var fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                model.FileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes);

                var columnMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Employee ID", "EmployeeID" },
                    { "Full Name", "FullName" },
                    { "Job Title", "JobTitle" },
                    { "Department", "Department" },
                    { "Business Unit", "BusinessUnit" },
                    { "Gender", "Gender" },
                    { "Ethnicity", "Ethnicity" },
                    { "Age", "Age" },
                    { "Hire Date", "HireDate" },
                    { "Country", "Country" },
                    { "City", "City" }
                };

                var rows = model.FileContent.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var dataRows = rows.Skip(1); // Skip the header row
                var dataTable = CreateDataTable(columnMapping.Values);

                foreach (var row in dataRows)
                {
                    var cells = row.Split(",");
                    if (cells.Length == columnMapping.Count)
                    {
                        var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                        for (var i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
                        {
                            var columnName = columnMapping.ElementAt(i).Value;
                            dataRow[columnName] = cells[i];
                        }

                        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                    }
                }

                await SaveDataToDatabase(dataTable);
            }
        }

        return View("Upload", model);
    }

    private DataTable CreateDataTable(IEnumerable<string> columnNames)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }

    private async Task SaveDataToDatabase(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.dev";
                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
                }
                await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that the `SaveDataToDatabase` method would save the updated table data to the database. However, it seems to be using the original `dataTable` object instead.

How can I modify the code to ensure that the updated data from the webpage is sent to the database instead of the original data? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which part in the code sends `updatedTableData` to the server?

Comment: @chetan, the comment in Javascript?

Comment: what makes you think the original data is being updated?  What really is happening is the data is not changing.  You need to debug your controller and see what is going wrong.  Make sure the datatable is being created with the new data.  If the datatable is empty your database will not get the new values.  If the datatable contains the updated values than issue is with the SaveDataToDatabase method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. It seems that I was not properly configuring the datatables.

Here is the updated codes:

##### Upload.cshtml

```
@model ImportModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Import Page";
}

<center>
    <h1>Import Data</h1>
</center>

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["ImportMessage"] as string))
{
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        @TempData["ImportMessage"]
    </div>
}

<form asp-controller="Import" asp-action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="my-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fileInput">Select File:</label>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="file" class="form-control-file" accept=".csv, application/vnd.ms-excel" required>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Display File Content</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.FileContent))
{
    <h4>File Contents:</h4>
    <div id="fileContents" class="table-responsive">
        <form asp-controller="Import" asp-action="Import" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="fileContent" value="@Model.FileContent" />
            <table id="editableTable" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var columnName in Model.FileContent.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First().Split(","))
                        {
                            <th>@columnName</th>
                        }
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var row in Model.FileContent.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1))
                    {
                        <tr>
                            @foreach (var cell in row.Split(","))
                            {
                                <td><input type="text" name="updatedData" value="@cell" /></td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />
            <button id="importBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Import</button>
            <button id="clearBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary">Home</a>
        </form>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        var importBtn = document.getElementById('importBtn');
        var clearBtn = document.getElementById('clearBtn');

        fileInput.addEventListener('change', function () {
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            if (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    document.getElementById('fileContents').innerHTML = e.target.result;
                    importBtn.disabled = false;
                    clearBtn.disabled = false;
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            } else {
                document.getElementById('fileContents').innerHTML = '';
                importBtn.disabled = true;
                clearBtn.disabled = true;
            }
        });

        clearBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            fileInput.value = '';
            document.getElementById('fileContents').innerHTML = '';
            importBtn.disabled = true;
            clearBtn.disabled = true;
        });
    </script>
}
```

##### ImportController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ImportController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ImportController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult Upload()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(ImportModel model)
    {
        if (model.File != null && model.File.Length > 0)
        {
            model.FileName = Path.GetFileName(model.File.FileName);

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await model.File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                var fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                model.FileContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes);
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Import(string fileContent, List<string> updatedData)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileContent))
        {
            var columnMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Employee ID", "EmployeeID" },
                { "Full Name", "FullName" },
                { "Job Title", "JobTitle" },
                { "Department", "Department" },
                { "Business Unit", "BusinessUnit" },
                { "Gender", "Gender" },
                { "Ethnicity", "Ethnicity" },
                { "Age", "Age" },
                { "Hire Date", "HireDate" },
                { "Country", "Country" },
                { "City", "City" }
            };

            var rows = fileContent.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var headerRow = rows[0]; // Get the header row
            var dataRows = rows.Skip(1); // Skip the header row
            var dataTable = CreateDataTable(columnMapping.Values);

            // Log the original and updated data in the console
            Console.WriteLine("Original Data:");
            Console.WriteLine(headerRow);
            foreach (var row in dataRows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(row);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.Count(); i++)
            {
                var cells = dataRows.ElementAt(i).Split(",");
                if (cells.Length == columnMapping.Count)
                {
                    var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                    for (var j = 0; j < cells.Length; j++)
                    {
                        var columnName = columnMapping.ElementAt(j).Value;
                        var updatedCellValue = updatedData[i * cells.Length + j];
                        dataRow[columnName] = updatedCellValue;
                    }

                    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                }
            }

            await SaveDataToDatabase(dataTable);
        }

        // Raise an alert for success
        TempData["ImportMessage"] = "Data imported successfully";

        return RedirectToAction("Upload");
    }

    private DataTable CreateDataTable(IEnumerable<string> columnNames)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(columnName);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }

    private async Task SaveDataToDatabase(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.dev";
                foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
                }
                await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(dataTable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```